# How to animate the android Imageview with random direction?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I want to develop the application like the below image

[image]

I want to animate the imageviews 2,3,4,5,6 to the imageview 1 and vice versa

Please any one help me how to do this

Comment: Want to animate all imageviews click on centered imageview??

Comment: @PiyushGupta I want to animate all imageviews when the activity is started not on click on centered imageview

Comment: Take a look at this link https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

Comment: @Krishna do you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int distance = 100; //the distance to move in pixels
int duration = 500; //the duration of the animation in ms

double direction = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

int translationX = Math.cos(direction) * distance;
int translationY = Math.sin(direction) * distance;

yourImageView.animate().translationX(translationX).translationY(translationY).setDuration(duration).start();
```

Comment: This answer helped me to get the idea to done my requirement. Thanks Mark